# Generating all points of grid from given vectors of vertical and horizontal coordinates - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a square grid of 10 by 10 points. `v1` is the vector of horizontal coordinates and `v2` is the vector that contains the vertical coordinates. From these two vectors, I want to construct all the 100 points. 
Here is a 2 by 2 example:

```
v1 = [1 2];
v2 = [3 4];
```

Then the 4 points I want to generate are:

```
p(1,:) = [1,3]
p(2,:) = [1,4]
p(3,:) = [2,3]
p(4,:) = [2,4]
```

How can this be done in MATLAB?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to horizontally concatenate the vectors?  What are the dimensions of your desired result?  Mx6?  What do the semicolons mean in your expression?

Comment: Do you mean concatenate vertically each vector repeated some number of times? Can't you use literally the code you posted?

Comment: Your comment on *yoh.lej*'s answer is clearer than this question! Go and edit this question according to your comment to make it something meaningful before we tell you which function that starts with `n` and ends with `d` you actually need!

Comment: Use `\`` around codes! This will make \`v1 = [1 2]\`  look a lot better: `v1 = [1 2]`

Comment: if i have two matrices a=[1 2; 1 2] and b =[3 4;3 4].How can I plot the points (1,3), (1,4),(2,3),(2,4) where each point is represented as a dot "."

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use `meshgrid` or even better: [`ndgrid`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html). The concept of both functions is the same, but `ndgrid` is more general and has a sorting of the output that is often more useful.

```
x = [1,2];
y = [3,4];
[X, Y] = ndgrid(x, y);
P = [X(:), Y(:)];
```

The call to `ndgrid` will generate two matrices `X` and `Y` which will have the structure of the mesh you want, and the values `X(i,j)` and `Y(i,j)` correspond to each other. So to get the points `P`, you just need to reshape those arrays to column vectors and concatenate them.

Comment: @mohamed: Please make sure to formulate your next question better before you post it! We don't want to flood stackoverflow with garbage and it was not clear at all what you meant by it! I made edits to your question, so that the title is actually meaningful and the formatting isn't that ugly. Please have a look at [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @mohamed: So did this solve your problem? I'd be happy if you accepted the answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: @mohamed - I'll be direct for everyone else who was trying to nudge in the right direction.  Accept this answer by going to the top of this post, and clicking on the checkmark icon that's to the left, below the up and down voting arrows.  Not doing this will probably discourage people from helping you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Neural Network Toolbox you are looking for the [combvec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/combvec.html) function, which creates all combinations from 2 vectors.

Example:

```
v1=[1 2] 

v2=[3 4]

V = combvec(v1,v2)
```

which outputs:

```
V =

     1     2     1     2
     3     3     4     4
```

Comment: Downside: This will only work with the neural network toolbox installed. But there is a built-in one we can use. I was hoping the OP would clean up his question a bit, before we gave him the answer...

Comment: Oh I did not notice that this Toolbox was required thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer that best helped you as 'accepted' so the thread is closed for future readers. Thanks and good luck!